# Extracting `a` from Applicative `f a`

Tags: haskell

[Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids#applicative-functors) offers the following exercise:

> Let's try implementing a function that takes a list of applicatives and 
>   returns an applicative that has a list as its result value.

LYAH gives the type signature `sequenceA' :: (Applicative f) => [f a] -> f [a]`

I started with `Applicative`, but wasn't sure how to extract `a` from `f a` in a general way for all `Applicative`'s.

So, I implemented it as a `Maybe`. Of course this is unacceptable for all `Applicative's.

```
import Control.Applicative

sequenceA' :: (Num a) =>  [Maybe a] -> Maybe [a] 
sequenceA' []  = pure []
sequenceA' xs = pure $ [extract' x | x <- xs ]

extract' :: (Num a) => Maybe a -> a 
extract' x  = case x of 
      Just y  -> y
      Nothing -> 0
```

How can I extract `a` from `f a` where `f` is an `Applicative`?

Comment: That type signature doesn't require you to extract anything from the `Applicative` instance. In fact, it requires you to inject *more* into it.

Comment: You might be interested in `Data.Traversable.sequenceA`.  It's a bit more general than this `sequenceA'` so it may be slightly tricky to follow though.

Comment: since others have posted some very nice answers to point you in the right direction, here's a mind expanding implementation: `sequenceA = traverse id`

Comment: I think you want to read ["Inside My World (Ode to Functor and Monad)"](http://blog.jle.im/entry/inside-my-world-ode-to-functor-and-monad). It doesn't cover `Applicative` but the same basic idea from the article (staying "inside a world") applies to your question.

Answer (score 10):

You can't in general. In fact, the `Maybe` example you gave is a good example of why since it requires it to be a `Num` instance. It wouldn't make sense for the `Maybe` `Applicative` in general, so that would be a counterexample to a general solution. Another counterexample would be `IO`. There is no valid `extract` implementation for `IO`.

To make a function that is general enough to work with all `Applicative` instances, you must be able to construct the function using only methods from `Applicative` and its super-class, `Functor`. There is no way to make `extract` using only `fmap`, `pure` and `(<*>)`.

Answer (score 6):

It's not necessary to take things out of the applicative functor to achieve this.

The great thing about applicative functors is they allow you to use ordinary functions on the results of each applicative computation, so
if you have applicatives `c1`, `c2` and `c3` of types `f a`, `f b`, `f c`
that produce values `v1`, `v2` and `v3` of types `a`, `b` and `c`,
but you actually want to use a function `g :: a -> b -> c -> d` on the values
to produce `g v1 v2 v3 :: d`, then you can do

```
g <$> c1 <*> c2 <*> c3
```

which has type `f d`.

So we can use the function (:) to join the first value out of our list of applicatives with the rest of them, so you can do someytthing like `(:) <$> thingThatGivesFirstValue <*> thing that gives the rest of the list`. So it'll be a nice recursion if you pattern match on the list of applicatives.

```
sequenceA' :: (Applicative f) => [f a] -> f [a]
sequenceA' [] = -- just give the empty list
sequenceA' (c:cs) = -- hmm. What could go here then?
```

so for example you should get

```
ghci> sequenceA' [getLine, getLine, getLine]
Hello
there
everyone
["Hello","there","everyone"]
ghci> sequenceA' [Just 3, Just 4, Just 5]
Just [3,4,5]
```

Here's an example function to help you along with the recursice case:

```
nth :: Applicative f => f Int -> f [a] -> f a
nth wrappedInt wrappedList = (!!) <$> wrappedInt <*> wrappedList
```

So you don't need to unwrap anything or get values out, the operators`<$> and <*>` let you do what you like inside.

```
nth (Just 3) (Just "Hello") == 'l'
```

Comment: Don't just give it away, please. It's an exercise.

Comment: +1 luqui. But remove the implementation and you get a very good answer IMHO

Comment: @luqui, Benesh, Fair point. I've edited out the answer in favour of some hints.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a hint:

```
foo :: Applicative f => f Int -> f Int -> f Int
foo fx fy = (+) <$> fx <*> fy    -- apply + "under" the functor

bar :: Applicative f => f a -> f [a] -> f [a]
bar fx fxs = ??? <$> fx <*> fxs  -- apply ??? "under" the functor

sequenceA' :: Applicative f => [f a] -> f [a]
sequenceA' []     = pure []   -- as in your solution
sequenceA' (x:xs) = let y  = x             -- :: f a
                        ys = sequenceA' xs -- :: f [a]
                    in ???
```

I use `let` in the last function to clarify the types which are involved. After you fill in the `???` you can of course remove the `let`.

Comment: The evaluation order of x previous to xs is not guaranteed in {let y = x ; ys = sequenceA' xs in ..} It's just functional code !!

Comment: @GabrielRiba Sure, but I never claimed otherwise... As I have written in the last lines, I am using `let` only to stress that you have a `f a` and a `f [a]` to combine, and that it should be removed in the final version.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract `a` from `f a` with pattern matching or evaluation, if `f` is not IO

```
import Control.Applicative
import System.IO
import Control.Monad.ST

-- with AndrewC sequenceA' definition

sequenceA' :: (Applicative f) => [f a] -> f [a]
sequenceA' [] = pure []
sequenceA' (c:cs) = (:) <$> c <*> sequenceA' cs

seqOfMaybes :: [Maybe a] -> [a]
seqOfMaybes listOfMb = case sequenceA' listOfMb of
                   Nothing -> []
                   Just list -> list


-- sequencing ST computations

compute :: a -> ST s a
compute x = return x

seqOfSTData :: [Int] -> [Int]
seqOfSTData vals = runST $ (sequenceA' (map compute vals) :: ST s [Int])


-- but you cannot escape the applicative f if f is IO

readAnInt :: IO Int
readAnInt = putStrLn "give me an Int>" >> hFlush stdout >> getLine >>= (return . read)

seqOfIO :: [IO a] -> IO [a]
seqOfIO listOfIO = sequenceA' listOfIO

main :: IO ()
main = do
        print $ seqOfMaybes [Just 3, Just 4, Just 5]
        print $ seqOfSTData [1,2,3]
        seqOfIO [readAnInt, readAnInt] >>= print
```